# Why i Get this Error : Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: facebook

Hi Wonder what the problem is >.<

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://forums.mysite.com/interface/facebook/xd_receiver.php#%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22sc%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fxd_receiver_v0.4.php%22%2C%22sf%22%3A%22loginStatus%22%2C%22sr%22%3A2%2C%22h%22%3A%22loginServer%22%2C%22sid%22%3A%220.695%22%2C%22t%22%3A0%7D%5B0%2C%22loginStatus%22%2C%22InitLogin%22%2C%7B%22baseDomain%22%3A%22levelupgames.ph%22%2C%22connectState%22%3A2%2C%22perms%22%3Anull%2C%22publicSessionData%22%3Anull%2C%22session%22%3Anull%2C%22settings%22%3A%7B%22inFacebook%22%3Afalse%2C%22locale%22%3A%22en_US%22%7D%7D%2Cfalse%5D from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/extern/login_status.php?api_key=b920fdb75dcba2cc06f3bf1b6dc22618&extern=2&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.mysite.com%2Finterface%2Ffacebook%2Fxd_receiver.php&locale=en_US. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 0):

This is a violation of of the browser [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  With minor exceptions, a frame can not access the DOM of another from a different domain.

Comment: Your question doesn't really provide any context.  Facebook's API can certainly be used without violating the same-origin policy.

Comment: Matthew, I think the question is valid. This is a popular problem because this implementation is the one suggested by the Facebook itself for the javascript SDK.

Comment: @Jhourlad, I didn't say the question was invalid.  It just needs a little more context (e.g. a link to the possibly incorrect Facebook docs).